# Primary key collision in scope of one trasaction

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a `postgresql` database, which heavily relies on events from the outside, e.g. administrator changing / adding some fields or records might trigger a change in overall fields structure in other tables.

There lies the problem, however, as sometimes the fields changed by the trigger function are primary key fields. There is a table, which uses two foreign keys ids as the primary key, as in example below:

```
#  | PK id1 | PK id2 |  data  |
0  |   1    |   1    |   ab   |
1  |   1    |   2    |   cd   |
2  |   1    |   3    |   ef   |
```

However, within one transaction (if I may call it such, since, in fact, it is a `plpgsql` function), the structure might be changed to:

```
#  | PK id1 | PK id2 |  data  |
0  |   1    |   3    |   ab   |
1  |   1    |   2    |   cd   |
2  |   1    |   1    |   ef   |
```

Which, as you might have noticed, changed the 0th record's second primary key to `3`, and the 2nd's to `1`, which is the opposite of what they were before.

It is 100% certain that after the function has taken its effect there will be no collisions whatsoever, but I'm wondering, how can this be implemented?

I could, in fact, use a synthetic primary key as a `BIGSERIAL`, yet there is still a need for those two ids to be `UNIQUE` constained, so it wouldn't do the trick, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a constraint as deferrable, for example a primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE elbat (id int,
                    nmuloc int,
                    PRIMARY KEY (id)
                                DEFERRABLE);
```

You can then use `SET CONSTRAINTS` in a transaction to set deferrable constraints as deferred. That means that they can be violated temporarily  during the transaction but must be fulfilled at the transaction's `COMMIT`.

Let's assume we have some data in our example table:

```
INSERT INTO elbat (id,
                   nmuloc)
                  VALUES (1,
                          1),
                         (2,
                          2);
```

We can now switch the IDs like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

UPDATE elbat
       SET id = 2
       WHERE nmuloc = 1;

SELECT *
       FROM elbat;
       
UPDATE elbat
       SET id = 1
       WHERE nmuloc = 2;
       
COMMIT;
```

There's no error even though the IDs are both `2` after the first `UPDATE`.
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=a6ec2a4db22e2526002eee38fbd27126)

More on that can be found in the documentation, e.g. in [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) (or [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)) and [`SET CONSTRAINTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html).